# Yum install command not executing from system command in perl

Tags: linux, perl, rpm, yum

I am trying to install a Linux RPM using `system("yum -y install MyRPM.rpm");` in a Perl script.

The problem I am facing is:

- The system command gets executed.
- It starts installing the RPM
- Then, just after the line "running transaction". The script hangs.

Output:

```
Running Transaction Test
Transaction Test Succeeded
Running Transaction
```

No output after this line and script hangs.

Usually after this line, if I run `yum install` from the terminal it displays:

```
Installing : myRPM [#################################]
```

But my Perl script hangs at this line.

To solve this, I wrote a bash script to perform the RPM installation  and in turn calling it in my perl script. But at the point where the bash script is called and starts executing the yum install command, the script hangs. On the other hand, if I execute the bash script as a standalone script it does the installation smoothly. I have no idea why the perl script  gets stuck in between the yum install.

I would really appreciate some help on this.

Comment: The output is:Running Transaction Test
Transaction Test Succeeded
Running Transaction

Comment: Have you tried suppressing the output?

    yum -q -y myrpm

then if it works you can very its installed with rpm

    rpm -qa | grep myrpm

Comment: I tried to suppress the output but the script still hangs at the yum install line.

Comment: Does this help? http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=957403

Comment: This did not work as well.

Comment: What do you get if you run it through strace?